# More elegant way to check for duplicates in C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

I wrote this code in C++ as part of a uni task where I need to ensure that there are no duplicates within an array:

```
// Check for duplicate numbers in user inputted data
    int i; // Need to declare i here so that it can be accessed by the 'inner' loop that starts on line 21
    for(i = 0;i < 6; i++) { // Check each other number in the array
        for(int j = i; j < 6; j++) { // Check the rest of the numbers
            if(j != i) { // Makes sure don't check number against itself
                if(userNumbers[i] == userNumbers[j]) {
                    b = true;
                }
            }
            if(b == true) { // If there is a duplicate, change that particular number
                cout << "Please re-enter number " << i + 1 << ". Duplicate numbers are not allowed:" << endl;
                cin >> userNumbers[i];
            }
        } // Comparison loop
        b = false; // Reset the boolean after each number entered has been checked
    } // Main check loop
```

It works perfectly, but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant or efficient way to check.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could sort the array in O(nlog(n)), then simply look until the next number. That is substantially faster than your O(n^2) existing algorithm. The code is also a lot cleaner. Your code also doesn't ensure no duplicates were inserted when they were re-entered. You need to prevent duplicates from existing in the first place.

```
std::sort(userNumbers.begin(), userNumbers.end());
for(int i = 0; i < userNumbers.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (userNumbers[i] == userNumbers[i + 1]) {
        userNumbers.erase(userNumbers.begin() + i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

I also second the recommendation to use a `std::set` - no duplicates there.

Comment: But if sort is O (n * log( n ) ) and then you have to do a O( n ) check of the array to find the duplicates after isn't your complexity then O( n^2 * log( n ) )?

Comment: No, it's O(n*log(n) + n) - you sort THEN search, not sort AND search for every operation of the sort.

Comment: This is certainly faster as 6 approaches infinity ;-)

Comment: @DeadMG: I do agree with your answer in general :-) That 6 (and the interactive replacement of dupes) might just be example code, but if not then I'd probably stick with what the questioner has, since it preserves the array in the order it was provided, without moving anything or taking a copy.

Comment: Correction: it should be "it's O(n log n)", of course. The solution presented above is O(n^2), however...

Comment: @paul_71: It is O(n log n). You sort once, then you iterate once. That's O(n log n).

Comment: @DeadMG:  You are right of course.  I was multiplying when I should have been adding.

Comment: @DeadMG No, it is not. This were true, if std::vector<T>::erase was O(1) which it is not. It is O(n) in general, which makes your solution O(n^2) in total. Though n is decreasing as you process the array (assume you have each element occuring twice) you have O(1) + O(n-1) for each call of erase. For a O(n log n) solution (which I think is the lower bound) see my answer below.

Comment: @paul_71: The cost of the erase is not part of the algorithm, as if you'll notice, the OP had a different action on duplicate detection which is not O(n). It was merely an example. It would be trivial to, for example, simply create a new array and O(1) insert into it, then replace the original with the new.

Comment: Right, if the pure duplicate detection suffices, sorting and a linear walk through the sequence is enough. Removing duplicates is a different cup of tea - and the way suggested above is O(n^2) and does not preserve the original ordering of the elements...

Comment: @paul_71: Question only asked for detection.

Answer (score 18):

The following solution is based on sorting the numbers and then removing the duplicates:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int userNumbers[6];

    // ...

    int* end = userNumbers + 6;
    std::sort(userNumbers, end);
    bool containsDuplicates = (std::unique(userNumbers, end) != end);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Well, the best answer would substitute `unique` with `adjacent_find`, as it doesn't check the whole container and shuffle away the duplicates, but instead just returns when it finds the first one.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, the fastest and as far I can see most elegant method is as advised above:

```
std::vector<int> tUserNumbers;
// ...
std::set<int> tSet(tUserNumbers.begin(), tUserNumbers.end());
std::vector<int>(tSet.begin(), tSet.end()).swap(tUserNumbers);
```

It is O(n log n). This however does not make it, if the ordering of the numbers in the input array needs to be kept... In this case I did:

```
    std::set<int> tTmp;
    std::vector<int>::iterator tNewEnd = 
        std::remove_if(tUserNumbers.begin(), tUserNumbers.end(), 
        [&tTmp] (int pNumber) -> bool {
            return (!tTmp.insert(pNumber).second);
    });
    tUserNumbers.erase(tNewEnd, tUserNumbers.end());
```

which is still O(n log n) and keeps the original ordering of elements in `tUserNumbers`.

Cheers,

Paul

Answer (score 7):

It is in extension to the answer by @Puppy, which is the current best answer.

PS : I tried to insert this post as comment in the current best answer by @Puppy but couldn't so as I don't have 50 points yet. Also a bit of experimental data is shared here for further help.

Both std::set and std::map are implemented in STL using Balanced Binary Search tree only. So both will lead to a complexity of O(nlogn) only in this case. While the better performance can be achieved if a hash table is used. std::unordered_map offers hash table based implementation for faster search. I experimented with all three implementations and found the results using std::unordered_map to be better than std::set and std::map. Results and code are shared below. Images are the snapshot of performance measured by [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/) on the solutions.

```
bool hasDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {
    size_t count = nums.size();
    if (!count)
        return false;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> tbl;
    //std::set<int> tbl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (tbl.find(nums[i]) != tbl.end())
            return true;
        tbl[nums[i]] = 1;
        //tbl.insert(nums[i]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**unordered_map** Performance (Run time was 52 ms here)
[image]

**Set/Map** Performance
[image]

Comment: Why net use `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::unordered_map`?

Answer (score 6):

You can add all elements in a set and check when adding if it is already present or not. That would be more elegant and efficient.

Comment: How do you do that? Add in a set I mean.

Comment: @Saladin Akara: have a look at std:set, it's part of STL.

Comment: Just a note: You don't have to check with std::set, you can just call insert and if there's a dupe, it'll magically disappear.

Comment: Of course, `std::set` can quickly become inefficient for larger data sets, which is one of the reasons why `std::unordered_set` is being added in C++0x. If you can use it, the latter can become much faster for larger data sets.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why this hasn't been suggested but here is a way in base 10 to find duplicates in O(n).. The problem I see with the already suggested O(n) solution is that it requires that the digits be sorted first.. This method is O(n) and does not require the set to be sorted. The cool thing is that checking if a specific digit has duplicates is O(1). I know this thread is probably dead but maybe it will help somebody! :)

```
/*
============================
Foo
============================
* 
   Takes in a read only unsigned int. A table is created to store counters 
   for each digit. If any digit's counter is flipped higher than 1, function
   returns. For example, with 48778584:
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
   [0] [0] [0] [0] [2] [1] [0] [2] [2] [0]

   When we iterate over this array, we find that 4 is duplicated and immediately
   return false.

*/
bool Foo(int number)
{
    int temp = number;
    int digitTable[10]={0};

    while(temp > 0)
    {
        digitTable[temp % 10]++; // Last digit's respective index.
        temp /= 10; // Move to next digit
    }

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (digitTable [i] > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. It will fail for negative numbers though

Comment: Yeah, that's easily solvable though. Just make the lookup table an array of pairs where first is positive count and second is negative count. Same algorithm works just check positive and negative

Answer (score 4):

It's ok, specially for small array lengths. I'd use more efficient aproaches (less than n^2/2 comparisons) if the array is mugh bigger - see DeadMG's answer.

Some small corrections for your code:

- Instead of `int j = i` write`int j = i +1` and you can omit your `if(j != i)` test
- You should't need to declare `i` variable outside the `for` statement.

Comment: I needed to declare `i` outside the first loop because I'd get an `i was not declared in this scope` error when I use it in the 'inner' for loop. Wasn't sure why it did that, but declaring outside the loop fixed the problem

Comment: @Saladin: It's a bug in your compiler. Declaring i inside the first for loop should make it accessible in the second.

Comment: @Saladin: And I am guessing your compiler is the < a very bad word here > Visual Studio 6.0, isn't it?

Comment: @Armen Nope - Using the GCC g++ mode.

Answer (score 3):

I think @Michael Jaison G's solution is really brilliant, I modify his code a little to avoid sorting. (By using unordered_set, the algorithm may faster a little.)

```
template <class Iterator>
bool isDuplicated(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    std::unordered_set<T> values(begin, end);
    std::size_t size = std::distance(begin,end);
    return size != values.size();
}
```

Comment: One drawback of this solution is that it doesn't work with input iterators, although there is no good reasons for it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @underscore_d, an elegant and efficient solution would be,

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <class Iterator>
bool has_duplicates(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    std::vector<T> values(begin, end);

    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
    return (std::adjacent_find(values.begin(), values.end()) != values.end());
}

int main() {
    int user_ids[6];
    // ...
    std::cout << has_duplicates(std::begin(user_ids), std::end(user_ids)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but you better make the Container a template parameter iso the iterator, this way it works with every container type.

Comment: I would honestly not even create a new container in this function but modify the existing range. If the user doesn't want their container modified, they can make a new vector outside this template.

Answer (score 1):

```
//std::unique(_copy) requires a sorted container.
std::sort(cont.begin(), cont.end());

//testing if cont has duplicates
std::unique(cont.begin(), cont.end()) != cont.end();

//getting a new container with no duplicates
std::unique_copy(cont.begin(), cont.end(), std::back_inserter(cont2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int main(){

    int arr[] = {3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); // Finding length of array

    std::sort(arr, arr+len);

    int unique_elements = std::unique(arr, arr+len) - arr;

    if(unique_elements == len) std::cout << "Duplicate number is not present here\n";
    else std::cout << "Duplicate number present in this array\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fast   O(N) time and space  solution
return first when it hits duplicate

```
template <typename T>
bool containsDuplicate(vector<T>& items) {
    return any_of(items.begin(), items.end(), [s = unordered_set<T>{}](const auto& item) mutable {
        return !s.insert(item).second;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough karma to post a comment. Hence a post.

```
   vector <int> numArray = { 1,2,1,4,5 };
   unordered_map<int, bool> hasDuplicate;
   bool flag = false;
   for (auto i : numArray)
   {
      if (hasDuplicate[i])
      {
         flag = true;
         break;
      }
      else
         hasDuplicate[i] = true;
   }

   (flag)?(cout << "Duplicate"):("No duplicate");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31965751)