# Explain std::vector<int>(tSet.begin(), tSet.end())

Tags: c++

In this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003584/more-elegant-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-c-array/4003950#4003950) there is the following line:

```
std::vector<int>(tSet.begin(), tSet.end()).swap(tUserNumbers);
```

Can someone explain the syntax of the portion before `.swap`?  Is there a name to it by which I could look it up?

Comment: Look up `constructor`

Comment: Copies the entire range of `tSet` into the vector and then swaps its contents with those of  `tUserNumbers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<int>(tSet.begin(), tSet.end())
//                          ^ iterator to begin of data range
// tSet.end() is iterator to end of data range
```

creates a temporary variable which is of type `std::vector<int>` by copying container named `tSet`

> Is there a name to it by which I could look it up?

Look at [this decription of vector constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

in particular at constructor (4):

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

which is called sometimes also a range constructor.