# Searching and sorting arrays

Tags: c++

I am taking an introductory level C++ class. I have to write a boolean function  that checks for duplicates along a vectors and returns true and false if no duplicates

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
bool has_duplicates(const vector <int> &v);


int main() {

    vector<int> Vec(8);
    Vec = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 5, 6 };
    has_duplicates(Vec);
    return 0;
}
bool has_duplicates(const vector<int>& v) {
    bool duplicatefound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // Check each other number in the array
        for (int j = i; j < 8; j++) { // Check the rest of the numbers 
            while (j != i) {// Makes sure don't check number against itself 
                if (v[i] == v[j]) {
                    cout << "duplicate found" << endl;
                    duplicatefound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return duplicatefound; // Reset the boolean after each number entered has been checked
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the thing you have tried? We want to help you. but we don't from 0.  share your idea.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. What is your **Q**uestion?

Comment: first start to create an array with some duplicate values. Then loop over the array. Inside the previous loop try to create an other loop and look for a way to return true if you find duplicate value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More elegant way to check for duplicates in C++ array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003584/more-elegant-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-c-array)

Comment: One problem (minus the syntax errors) you have that you allow i to equal j in the following `if (v[i] == v[j]) {`  This will make has_duplicates always return true.

Comment: i inserted a while statement while (j != i) before that let me post an update program

Comment: Use an `if` instead of `while` for that or combine the 2 conditionals in one using &&

Comment: @drescherjm it worked with the while i didn't put the function in a cout statement hence the issue i was getting

Comment: With the while you should have had an infinite loop when v[i] != v[j] since neither i nor j were changing in the while (i != j) {} loop.

Comment: i introduced the if loop instead while actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple solution to your problem:

1. Iterate through your array, using a loop: 
   `for(int i=0; i < array_length; i++)`
2. Within this loop, make use of another loop, to check whether any value prior to the one, to which `i` is pointing, is equal to `your_array[i]`. If this is the case you have found a duplicate and can `return true`, else the loops will just run until the end of the array is reached and then you can `return false`.
   Thus your entire function would be something like:

   ```
   bool contains_duplicates(int array[], int len) {
       for(int i=0; i < len; i++) {
           for(int j=0; j < i; j++) {
               if(array[j]==array[i]) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```

Hope I could help, cheers! 
lindebear

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using stack flow so i don't know how to copy my code well but mine looks almost like yours just the bool duplicate _found false . I will try it and get back to you

Comment: Sorry I actually just came up with a better solution! Check here again!

Comment: Btw. it would help a lot, if you could post the solution you came up with so far.

Comment: Just did up there it is giving me two errors when i run it on microsoft visual

Comment: I just tested my function from above and for me it seems to be working...
However I'm using arrays, not std::vectors... ;)

Comment: I solved the errors they were plain syntax errors . Let me try your see how it works

Comment: its running but isn't it supposed to display 1 or 0 which it isnt

Comment: Well, with the code you posted above, you did not include a

`std::cout << has_duplicates(Vec);`

Comment: Thank you very much you have been of great help its finally worked

Comment: No problem man! :D Happy to help!

Btw. can you check my answer as "solved" ;) (Really need the reputation haha)

Answer (score -1):

You can use templates to extend the type contained on vector like this. This solution reduces the algorithm complexity to O(n log n) which is better than O(n^2) from your nested loop, it doesn't mean it will be faster always but it make a difference on large vectors.

```
template< typename T>
bool hasDuplicates(std::vector<T> vect) {
    std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());
    T last;
    typename vector<T>::iterator it;
    for(it = vect.begin(); it < vect.end(); it++) {
        if (vect.begin() != it) {
            if(last == *it) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        last = *it;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am not conversant with templates ?

Comment: It helps you to forget the type in some situations like this one, you can have vectors of integers, doubles, etc.