# Vector "erase" and "at" producing an error (c++)

Tags: c++, vector

I am using the algorithm provided in [More elegant way to check for duplicates in C++ array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003584/more-elegant-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-c-array) in Order to print the duplicate elements.

```
   #include <random>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    
    /*Complexity: O(n log n). You sort once, then you iterate once*/
    void function_1(std::vector<int> t)
    {
      cout << "The duplicate elements are: \n";
      std::sort(t.begin(), t.end());
      for(int i = 0; i < t.size() - 1; i++)
      {
          if (t[i] == t[i + 1]) 
          {
          t.erase(t.at(i));
          i--;
          }
      }
    }
    
    
    int main()
    {
       std::vector<int> test{1,2,1,3,2,4};
    
       function_1(test);
      
      return 0;
    }
```

---

## Problem

I am getting the following error at `t.erase(t.at(i));`

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type&)’
    t.erase(t.at(i));
```

I don't understand why I am having the error above.

Thank you

Comment: What type of parameter does `vector::erase` require?  Did you read the documentation for `vector`?

Comment: Note: signed unsigned trouble:` i + 1 <  t.size()` is better than `i < t.size() - 1`. However, consider an unsigned i.

Comment: @OP FYI, `test.erase(std::unique(test.begin(), test.end()), test.end());` removes the duplicates from a sorted vector.

Comment: Just for clarity, the the erase bit from code that you copied from the answer in the linked question is simply wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that this algorithm is _O(n log n)_? In the worst case (all dupes), you'll end up repeatedly erasing and shuffling all the elements in the vector, on top of your sorting and iterating. I wonder whether the burden that scenario takes of the sort phase somehow amortizes against the shuffling, though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector::erase` requires an iterator to the location you wish to erase. You;re providing a reference to a stored value instead.

You could instead:

```
t.erase(std::next(t.begin(), i));
```

Comment: @Smeeheey still does not work. `std::advance` returns `void`. What you want is `std::next`.

Comment: Yes, true again and even better

Answer (score 2):

vector::erase requires an iterator - not an element type, so you should change:

```
t.erase(t.at(i));
```

to

```
t.erase(t.begin() + i);
```

to make it compile