# C++ check if the array contains duplicates

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have vector of strings, and I need to check if the array contains duplicates:

```
std::vector<std::string> data{};
const bool notContainsDuplicates = ...;
```

Can I solve this problem with standard library?

Comment: ***Can I solve this problem with standard library?*** Probably yes, but not sure what is your end goal or actual requirement.

Comment: Can you sort the vector (or a copy of the vector) first?  That would make the job a lot easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [More elegant way to check for duplicates in C++ array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003584/more-elegant-way-to-check-for-duplicates-in-c-array)

Comment: I can't sort and change vector

Comment: My -1 for you not explaining the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, using a standard library set to count the number of unique entries, if this is the same as the length of the input array there are no duplicates (another option is to use an unordered_map) :

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <string_view> // edit : added
#include <vector>
#include <set>

bool contains_duplicates(const std::vector<std::string>& input)
{
    // edit removed : std::set<std::string> set{ input.begin(), input.end() };
    std::set<std::string_view> set{ input.begin(), input.end() };
    return (set.size() != input.size());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> no_dups{ "hello","this","does","not","contain","duplicates" };
    std::vector<std::string> dups{ "hello","this","does","contain","duplicates","hello","this" };

    assert(!contains_duplicates(no_dups));
    assert(contains_duplicates(dups));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::set<std::string_view>` would avoid copying the strings

Comment: You could reduce the function to a single line:  `return std::set<std::string_view>(input.begin(), input.end()).size() != input.size();`

Comment: @AlanBirtles A thanks for that feedback didn't think of that. But it sure would be an improvement.

Comment: Edit : Added the string_view solution